# Where can I find internal Python scripts

Tags: python

I've made around 30 python scripts using the built in blender python editor.

I need to compare changes to the scripts with a different version of the scripts.

Is there anyway I can find the individual python files in windows file explorer?

The only other alternative I see is copy and pasting all the python scripts out of blender into their own files.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my temporary solution, I export all of the python files by running this script...I have a bad feeling this could be done much easier

```
import bpy
import os

numtexts = len(bpy.data.texts)
texts = bpy.data.texts

for i in range(0,numtexts):
    f = open(os.path.normpath("scripts/"+texts[i].name),'w')
    numLines = len(texts[i].lines)
    for j in range(0,numLines):
        f.write(texts[i].lines[j].body)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```